# Cannot open a file in python even through open() function

Tags: python, file-io

I am running the below python code:

```
from sys import argv
script,filename = argv
txt = open(filename)

print(f"Here's your file {filename}: ")
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again: ")
file_again = input(">")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

Now the file(**file15.txt**) I have is the same as the current working directory. I checked that via the os.getcwd() command.

But I see this error after running the script:

```
No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\PycharmProjects\\Sample\\file15.txt'
```

I checked other answers and verified that the txt file is in the same  directory as the current working directory. I even tried to use the absolute path in the argument but am still seeing the same error.

Please help me out.

Comment: it seems you don't have this file. Check if there is no mistake in your path. Use `print(filename)` before `open()`

Comment: Are you doing the exercises from Zed A Shaw's Learning Python 3 the hard way? Because I tried the same ex15 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Extensions could be hidden in the Windows Explorer, so if you see the correct filename maybe the real name of the file is `file15.txt.txt`.

Comment: @vesuvius Yes, I am. Not sure why it's not working for me.

Comment: Try the method @Matthias suggested. It could work

Comment: @Matthias Thanks! That worked! I removed the txt extention from the text file and ran the program. It worked fine now. Ahh, the nuances of computing !!